# During prepareForSegue get [UIViewController <null selector>] when try to assign value to property?

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, segue

during the prepareForSegue I try to assign a value to property and get the error

> 2012-05-09 23:14:22.122 LeakSpotter[17709:15b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setCoordLong:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa86e930'

header:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *CoordLong;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *CoordLat;
```

They are sythesized.

> -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

```
NSLog(@"Fired segue %@", [segue identifier]);
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"returnToLeakSpotter"]){
    NSLog(@"Return to leak spotter segue...");
    //ContactsViewController *cvc = (ContactsViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

}else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"gotoTakePhoto"]) {
    NSLog(@"Go to photo view");
    takePhotoViewController *takePhotoC = [segue destinationViewController];

    takePhotoC.CoordLong = @"-9.88";
    takePhotoC.CoordLat = @"45.45";
```

Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you haven't set the view controller subclass on your takePhotoViewController in the storyboard, so it is instantiating a base UIViewController (as seen in the error) which doesn't know what CoordLat is.

By the way, by convention class names start with an upper case letter and variables/properties with a lower case letter, you seem to have it the other way round.

Comment: I realised that what I am doing is trying upcast to takePhotoViewController which is why those additional properties are causing the runtime exception. I was lead to understand that this is the way to 'communicate' with the child view via a segue. But now I am wondering how this can be done practically.

Comment: Your code is fine. The problem is in your storyboard, I think. Find the view controller that te segue links to. Select it, and in the identity inspector, make sure the class is set to your correct subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to cast your viewController since destinationViewController returns a UIViewController by default.

```
takePhotoViewController *takePhotoC = (takePhotoViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

Comment: That would help with compilation warnings, but the question is about a run time error. destinationViewController returns whatever the class of the destination is - which will be UIViewController or a subclass.